# Unable to record on MAC Safari 7.0.5 : AudioSystem.isLineSupported returns false on Safari but true on Firefox

Tags: java, safari, osx-server

We have an java applet containing record option to perform recording which is not working in Safari browser, but it is working in Firefox browser on same MAC system.

System Details :
MAC OS : 10.9.4
Safari : 7.0.5
Firefox : 28
Java applet plug-in : 1.7 update 60

We are using java Sound APIs like AudioSystem.isLineSupported() for checking whether line are supported on system before recording and playback operation. After printing the result of all mixer objects on the system, we are getting different behavior for Safari and Firefox browser.

Logs:

### On Safari

```
2014-08-01 13:56:36:098 There are 3 mixer info objects
2014-08-01 13:56:36:099 Mixer Name:Default Audio Device
2014-08-01 13:56:36:100 Mixer Name:Built-in Output
2014-08-01 13:56:36:101 Mixer Name:Port Built-in Output
2014-08-01 13:56:36:113 line:SPEAKER target port
```

### On Firefox

```
2014-08-01 13:13:59:974 There are 5 mixer info objects
2014-08-01 13:13:59:974 Mixer Name:Default Audio Device
2014-08-01 13:13:59:975 line:interface TargetDataLine supporting 14 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes
2014-08-01 13:13:59:975 Mixer Name:Built-in Input
2014-08-01 13:13:59:978 line:interface TargetDataLine supporting 14 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes
2014-08-01 13:13:59:978 Mixer Name:Built-in Output
2014-08-01 13:13:59:979 Mixer Name:Port Built-in Input
2014-08-01 13:13:59:980 Mixer Name:Port Built-in Output
2014-08-01 13:13:59:981 line:SPEAKER target port
```

We can see that there are no line corresponding to Mixer Audio Device and also there is no Mixer available for "Built-in Input" type in Safari logs. We are not able to understand why the system level details are different in Safari browser.

Also in case we by-pass isLineSupported() function and call AudioSystem.getLine() function, it throws following exception:

```
2014-08-01 10:55:00:677 [DELEGATE-RECORD] ERROR JavaSoundHelper::getCaptureLine - Exception while getting a capture line for AudioFormat: PCM_SIGNED 8000.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No line matching interface TargetDataLine supporting format PCM_SIGNED 8000.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian is supported.
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getLine(AudioSystem.java:476)
    at JavaSoundHelper.getCaptureLine(JavaSoundHelper.java:405)
    at JSoundRecordMPDevice.selectAndOpenCaptureLine(JSoundRecordMPDevice.java:559)
    at JSoundRecordMPDevice.recordUIRequest(JSoundRecordMPDevice.java:356)
    at recordUIRequest(RecorderMPController.java:1058)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2014-08-01 10:55:00:677 [DELEGATE-RECORD] WARN JSoundRecordMPDevice::selectAndOpenCaptureLine() - getCaptureLine() failed for cache format: PCM_SIGNED 8000.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian
```

Can anyone please help in understanding why line is not supported in Safari but supported in Firefox on same MAC system?

Comment: Were you able to fix that?